# How to grab total physical memory from Kernel

Tags: c, performance, time, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am using `linux/mm.h`

```
struct sysinfo mem_info;
```

then totalMemory = mem_info.totalram;

That gives me how much ram my device has. Now, how do I get the amount of memory that is being used? I would really hate it to have to go through every running process and calculate sum of ram being used.

Comment: how do I use that in code?

Comment: Same way `/usr/bin/top` does. Just read it in as text and do a sub-string match. It is specifically designed for this sort of usage, so no nasty surprises in parsing the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic approach it to follow what the common Linux utilities do, that is to open the `/proc/meminfo` file as text and parse it.

Here's an example from busybox implementation:

```
/*
 * Revert to manual parsing, which incidentally already has the
 * sizes in kilobytes. This should be safe for both 2.4 and
 * 2.6.
 */
 fscanf(fp, "MemFree: %lu %s\n", &mfree, buf);

/*
 * MemShared: is no longer present in 2.6. Report this as 0,
 * to maintain consistent behavior with normal procps.
 */
if (fscanf(fp, "MemShared: %lu %s\n", &shared, buf) != 2)
    shared = 0;

fscanf(fp, "Buffers: %lu %s\n", &buffers, buf);
fscanf(fp, "Cached: %lu %s\n", &cached, buf);
```

Line 535 here: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/busybox/procps/top.c

Comment: Question, how often does that file get updated? I might have to run the code you posted a few times in a 10 minute window.

Comment: This is not a real file. When the `read` system call hits the kernel, the kernel will invoke the necessary API calls and format the results as text (so the info will be "up to a microsecond" at the moment of reading). You just need to make sure it is not buffered by the libc or some other user space library.